# Change active auto-renewable subscription on iOS

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

Is it possible to switch between active auto-renewable subscriptions on iOS?

For example:
I have an auto-renewable subscription 'family' configured in iTunes Connect

- Package A (1 week)
- Package B (1 month)
- Package C (3 months)

A user subscribes to package A for the first time and is billed every week. All works fine.
Let's assume that the user decides at one point to upgrade to Package B. Is this possible from within an iOS app?

As far as my tests show, it's not possible. The sandbox appstore's response is that i'm already subscribed to this package and returns a cancel error for the Package B transaction but simultaneously returns a purchased event with the latest receipt from package A (the original) which basicly means i keep giving this user the content for package A and he/she never gets to upgrade.